# Specifying resource in Stackdriver logging

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-stackdriver

I have a problem with custom metric for Google Stackdriver logging. I have created a simple metric for 404 errors, with this filter:

```
resource.type="gce_instance" textPayload: "HTTP" textPayload: "404" logName: "logs/apache-access"
```

Everything is working ok, but when I try to create chart in Stackdriver, I can't specify resource, what results, that Stackdriver don't know from where it should takes data.

[Printscreen from Stackdriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfE1S.png)
[Another printscreen from Stackdriver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD31A.png)

Answer (score 0):

Waiting for new events in log solved problem.